# function pointers declared in the moment of usage

Tags: c++

In javascript it's possible to do things like this:

```
SomeObject.somefunction(function(someparameters){
//do some things.
});
```

like in jquery each function:

```
$('.rawdata').each(function(index){
$(this).attr('some',index);
});
```

I searched and saw that in c/c++ we can use functions as parameters using function pointers, but didn't found a way to do some thing like the above one: to declare the function that will be pointed in the moment that it will be used. So is this possible? If it isn't, what would you recommend to use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B), added to C++ in the latest standard (C++11).

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// ...
// Double each element in the vector
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (int elem) { return 2*elem; });
```

The parameter that will receive the function will have to be either a template (whose precise type will be automatically deducted from the lambda function itself), either `std::function<>` (a type-erasure class designed to hold any type of "callable thing" with the given prototype).

By the way, function pointers aren't the only way to pass a function-like object to a procedure in C++ even before the C++11 standard: any object that overloads `operator()` (i.e. the function call operator) can be called as a function, and is said to be a "functor". Functors are quite ubiquitous when programming with the STL<sup>1</sup> algorithms.

---

1. @nitpickers: I know and I don't care, we all know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

That's an anonymous method in JavaScript. C++ doesn't have anonymous methods, so the exact behavior can't be replicated.

You could use, as you said, callbacks, but you have to declare them in advance, not when they are used.

Comment: Actually, in C++11 (the latest C++ standard) you can, using lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x has lambdas which is could do the same thing.

Comment: There is no more C++0x it is C++11!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda functions in C++11. For example assuming you `push_back` some integers into a `vector`, you can erase the odd numbers like this:

```
vector<int> v;
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
      [] (int e) { return e%2 == 1; }), v.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't wait for C++0x (now C++11)?

Use boost.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/lambda.html

Comment: There is no more C++0x it is C++11!

Comment: Regardless. If my compiler doesn't support C++11, boost is an option.